# Ошибка при установке расширения через composer в yii2

Tags: yii2, composer

Хочу установить расширение ElFinder для Yii2 через composer. Выдает такую ошибку:

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Лучше бы показали на что именно ругается, скорее всего какие-то зависимости не установлены, либо PHP не до конца настроен.

Comment: @noxom Я использую консоль Open Server'а - это лучший локальный веб-сервер для Windows, думаю там всё хорошо настроено. И я не до конца понял, что вы имели в виду под: "Лучше бы показали на что именно ругается". Composer выдает только эту ошибку, но могу скинуть скриншот всей консоли, возможно вы там увидите что именно у меня не так.

Answer (score 0):

Рейтинга не хватает, чтобы писать комментарий.

Не ставил сам `ElFinder`. Не понимаю, какая установка вообще происходит. В `composer` же просто копирования файлов и автозапуски еще бывает скриптов - вроде даже и `php` - после скачивания. Ну тогда, наверно, придется в гайде `ElFinder` на `github'е`, наверно, порыскать. Как бы мой ответ и не ответ вовсе. Комментарии просто не могу пока оставлять.